# How to feed Word 2010 (.docx) documents/templates with data from MySQL database?

Tags: docx, mailmerge

What would be the best approach to replace placeholders in a .docx document (Word 2010) with data coming from a MySQL database?

Can I just open the file using a server side language and do a string replace per each placeholder?

Is there any existing tool/library available?

Thanks

Comment: Do a regular Word mail merge?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I guess it works only for mails and Access database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use PHP the most complete available solution is [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com).

You may check in the tutorial how to substitute placeholder variables by data coming from any data source (like a MySQL DB).

In particular, you may populate table rows with an indefinite number of entries and you may delete whole blocks of the Word document depending on the data fed to the application or build dynamical Word charts.

You may check the available DEMO for a simple but quite illustrative example (its inner workings are explained in the tutorial section).

Answer (score 3):

**Disclosure: I lead the [docx4j](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j) project **

There are heaps of existing tools/libraries available!

Yes, you can just do a string replace, but that is a brittle approach, since Word may have split the string across runs.

You can use MERGEFIELDs, or content control data binding.

docx4j supports all three approaches, but content control data binding is the most powerful.

- [ContentControlsMergeXML](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ContentControlsMergeXML.java)
- [MERGEFIELDs](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsMailMerge.java)
- [VariableReplace](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/VariableReplace.java)

One thing to consider especially is **"repeats"**.  If you want say a row of a table in Word, for each matching row in your MySQL table, then you need a way to make this happen.

docx4j does this with a "repeat" content control around the table row; whichever solution you choose, I'd make sure up front that it can handle repeats.

Comment: I use the docx4j solution and I can attest to it. It's super fast and very easy to implement because of all of the sample code is provided. I have posted a sample implementation of docx4j as a web service called docx4j-ws to illustrate how easy it is to take their sample code and implement it as a web service. The fully working web service project can be found here: https://github.com/sylnsr/docx4j-ws The nice thing about using docx4j through a web service is that the client can be written in your language of choice.

Answer (score 3):

Disclosure: I work for Invantive.

Using Invantive Composition (http://www.invantive.com/products/invantive-composition) you can fill Word documents (letters, legal pleadings, insurancy policies) with data from a database (IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, Teradata and SQL Server) and then fully change the contents at will manually. It is intended for real Microsoft Word end-users (both the guys that make the template and the ones that use it) that access the databases through a central webservice and models with queries. Invantive Composition allows nested repeating groups of data and lay-out. Integrates into Microsoft Word using click once.

In the past, I personally have also been using JasperReports (http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) to generate letters using the RTF output target of JasperReports. It is free and works fine as long as you do not want to edit the output more than a few words and have Java/SQL development skills. Just as Invantive Composition it works fine for large numbers of different reports.

As long as you can control the environment completely, you can also consider using RTF as intermediate language (not for end-users, only real developers). Save document as RTF,  replace parts of the text you need to be replacable, write a webservice that accepts the parameter and dumps back the resulting RTF. Takes some time to generate more complex tables (tables are obviously something invented by the human race after the RTF specification was written :-) This approach only works with very limited number of templates and when you have sufficient developer time available to get it up and running and stabilized.

As an independent reviewer, I have also seen cases where XML templates were used, but the results were not as good as with JasperReports.

Answer (score 1):

You can use open [Open XML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) and replace your placeholders like [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/DanBedassa/archive/2009/01/16/dynamically-generating-word-2007-.docx-documents-using-.net.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

*Disclosure: I lead the docxgenjs project*

I think you shouldn't have to code everything by yourself, that's why I created a **[Mustache-like](http://mustache.github.io/)** templating engine for docx

Demo:

http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxgenjs/examples/demo.html

Repo

https://github.com/edi9999/docxgenjs

It is JS-based and works client and server side.

Comment: I went for PHPDocX for that project but thank you for this suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use server side language to do it. 
Check on apache POI.

http://poi.apache.org

Comment: Why do I have to use a Java interface?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I read the above esp the comments and Ivantive looks impressive - but the solution I needed was much simpler. Use Selection.Range.InsertDatabase in Word to fetch records from an access database or excel spreadsheet or even just another word document. With the access solution you can choose the layout of the records to fetch and have it fetch just particular recordds based on a field (eg ID). Google the words above and it'll take you to MS guidance and an example VB script. Worked well in just a few mins. Now looking for VB script that asks the person what ID they want from the dbase and we're done.

Answer (score 0):

it uses docx templates that have merge fields with java objects (the objects have the information you load from mysql or any other source). The xdoc report is an project for java language, the home page of the project is https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclosure: I create the templ4docx project *

Hello

You can use templ4docx java library, which is on maven central repository, so you can just add it to your maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pl.jsolve</groupId>
    <artifactId>templ4docx</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example usage:

```
    Docx docx = new Docx("E:\\template.docx");
    Variables variables = new Variables();
    variables.addTextVariable(new TextVariable("${firstName}", "John"));
    variables.addTextVariable(new TextVariable("${lastName}", "Sky"));
    docx.fillTemplate(variables);
    docx.save("E:\\filledTemplate.docx");
```

More details you can find here: http://jsolve.github.io/java/templ4docx/